# Difference when Putting Lower-cased Alphabet into Set

Tags: scala, haskell, set

Why the difference when putting the lower-cased alphabet into a `Set`?

**Haskell**

```
λ: import Data.Set as S
λ: Prelude.foldr (\e acc -> S.insert e acc) S.empty ['a' .. 'z']
fromList "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
```

**Scala**

```
scala> ('a' to 'z').toList.toSet
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Char] = Set(e, s, x, n, j, y, t,               
     u, f, a, m, i, v, q, b, g, l, p, c, h, r, w, k, o, z, d)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The default set implementation of scala is a hash set, so it is not ordered. The default set implementation in Haskell is a sorted set, which is ordered. (You need an `Ord` instance to insert a new element: `insert :: Ord a => a -> Set a -> Set a`)

To preserve order in scala, you would have to use a SortedSet, like this:

```
scala> import scala.collection.immutable._
scala> ('a' to 'z').to[SortedSet]
res4: scala.collection.immutable.SortedSet[Char] = TreeSet(a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r, s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z)
```

Here is a bit of background about the different choices:

Scala chooses a hash-based implementation because that is common in the JVM world, and because hashtables are usually quite a bit faster than sorted collections. The downside of this is that hash codes introduce some non-determinism, especially when combined with classes that use the default hash code implementation.

Haskell places purity over performance, so it chooses the more deterministic sorted collections.

Comment: Are (both of) you talking about *insertion* order or *natural* order of elements?

Comment: @SillyFreak `TreeSet` orders elements by natural order, not by insertion order.

Comment: I know, my comment was meant to point out the ambiguity in the (now deleted) comment, and to a lesser degree in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

`Set` is only a name, describing a data structure that isn't ordered and doesn't allow duplicate elements. Everything else is basically implementation dependent.

You have now experienced that a Set in Haskell is ordered, i.e. its elements need an `Ord` instance that defines the less-than relation for them. Scala's default implementation of the `Set` trait seems to be a HashSet, therefore the order seems random; actually it reflects the order of buckets elements are put in.

In many cases when a set is the right data structure, ordering doesn't matter (checking membership, keeping track of the number of distinct objects, ...). If it does, there are specialized options in Scala that have a stricter contract than the `Set` trait, just like Java: `SortedSet` for elements that have a logical ordering, or `LinkedHashSet`, which preserves insertion order for iteration, but uses the hash set data structure for the usual set operations.

Comment: The Haskell `Set` doesn't preserve insertion order; it stores the elements of the set in order. It's implemented with a size balanced binary tree.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure about that. I removed the irrelevant information